# What is the best container of containers to use in Unity?

Tags: javascript, c#, unity-game-engine, containers

So I want to use a container of containers to store dialogue in, but have recently found out that Unity doesn't like things like arrays of records or arrays of tuples. What's the best way to store this information so I can have one container which holds containers containing each bit of dialogue similar to this:

```
var example = [
("Name","Line1","Line2","Line3")
];
```

Answers for either C# or JS are greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: You can use a c# `List` of string, just make sure you include the list reference at the top of the file `using System.Collections.Generic;` Or you can just create a class which will start the name as a string and then a `List` of strings which is the dialogue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd make a wrapper class that holds all of the information necessary for a single dialog entry,

```
class Dialog {
    public String name;
    public String line1;
    public String line2;
    public String line3;

    //constructor, etc.
}
```

And then I'd store those into an an `ArrayList<Dialog>` (typed, dynamic array from `System.Collections.Generic;` as @Canvas commented).

With a little cleverness, you could even make branching conversation trees.  Although there I'd probably forgo the array and just make the conversation a linked list.

Comment: I would do that but I'd use a Dictionary with an enum to store the Dialog. It depends on how OP uses the Dialogs though.

Comment: @Stud Mmm, definitely.  There's a number of solutions that depend on precise need.  That's one of the challenges of moving on to larger projects: figuring out how to find out about data structures that already exist and do exactly what you need (like guava caches, was doing something once where those were appropriate, but had no idea they existed until I was bumbling around trying to reinvent the wheel).

Comment: Thank you very much! Just a follow up question: how can I access the value at a specific index of the array list? My searches on this have been fruitless so far.

Comment: `ArrayList` is accessed via zero-indexing, same as a static array.  Some languages might not have `[]` support, but it will provide a `get()` method instead.  Unity is the latter, IIRC (I work in Unity often enough, but things are blurry away from the IDE).